# How do I remove excess space when resizing screen on the right?

Tags: html, css

When I resize, it will have a big block of space on the right which I do not want but instead I would like the box to resize such that it fit properly in the container.

Edit: I space-between does not do what I want, so I want it to be like it is that is when u make the screen smaller there will be less box but I do not want the extra space on the right when resizing

```css
.container{
    width: 100%;

    /* justify-content: center; */
    /* align-items: center; */
    text-align: center;
}


#boxes {
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    
    /* IE and Edge */
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    scrollbar-width: none;

    max-width: 79%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 70vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    /* justify-content: space-between; */
    /* padding-left: 10px; */
}
#boxes::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}


.box{
    background: blueviolet;
    min-width: 120px;
    max-width: 180px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 10px;
    
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

.box img{
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 75%;
}
.box p{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    


  
}

.title{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.subtext{
    height: 23%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
.subtext::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
.title{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.subtext{
    height: 23%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
.subtext::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="-1">
        <script src="./jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <title>Movies</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </div class= "container">

        <div id = "boxes">
            <div class="box">
                <img src= ${img}>
                <div class = "subtext">     
                <p class = "title">${title}</p>
                <p class = "year">${year}dbfdfbbfsfeeadwaawwda</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <img src= ${img}>
                <div class = "subtext">     
                <p class = "title">${title}seefs</p>
                <p class = "year">${year}esfesdbffdbbfdf</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <img src= ${img}>
                <div class = "subtext">     
                <p class = "title">${title}sefsfe</p>
                <p class = "year">${year}eesesfdfbfdbbfdfbd</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <img src= ${img}>
                <div class = "subtext">     
                <p class = "title">${title}sfeeeeeeee</p>
                <p class = "year">${year}sfeeeeeeeeeeee</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    <div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I see that `justify-content: space-between;` is commented out in the CSS of `#boxes`.  Surely that's the easiest way to achieve what you are looking for?

Comment: Also, please don't just copy and paste the same text 6 times over.  If the site is indicating you should add more content to the question then do that

Comment: space-between does not do what I want. I do not want it to have a big gap in between but instead I want it to be like justify content start without that extra space

Comment: do you want the items to fill the remaining space?

Comment: I actually want the container to resize to fill in the space. Tho I initially thought it will only be the boxes but since it had a max-width it make it impossible to remove the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get rid of your `max-width` on your `.box` and use `flex: 1` instead of `flex-grow: 1`, the boxes will fill the space it's given while maintaining a `min-width` value. Is this what you're going for?

```css
.container{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}


#boxes {
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: baseline;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    max-width: 79%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 70vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#boxes::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}


.box{
    background: blueviolet;
    min-width: 120px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 10px;
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

.box img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 75%;
}
.box p{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;  
}

.title{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.subtext{
    height: 23%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
.subtext::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
.title{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.subtext{
    height: 23%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
.subtext::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class= "container">

        <div id = "boxes">
            <div class="box">
                <img src= ${img}>
                <div class = "subtext">     
                <p class = "title">${title}</p>
                <p class = "year">${year}dbfdfbbfsfeeadwaawwda</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <img src= ${img}>
                <div class = "subtext">     
                <p class = "title">${title}seefs</p>
                <p class = "year">${year}esfesdbffdbbfdf</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <img src= ${img}>
                <div class = "subtext">     
                <p class = "title">${title}sefsfe</p>
                <p class = "year">${year}eesesfdfbfdbbfdfbd</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <img src= ${img}>
                <div class = "subtext">     
                <p class = "title">${title}sfeeeeeeee</p>
                <p class = "year">${year}sfeeeeeeeeeeee</p>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="box">
                <img src= ${img}>
                <div class = "subtext">     
                <p class = "title">${title}sfeeeeeeee</p>
                <p class = "year">${year}sfeeeeeeeeeeee</p>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="box">
                <img src= ${img}>
                <div class = "subtext">     
                <p class = "title">${title}sfeeeeeeee</p>
                <p class = "year">${year}sfeeeeeeeeeeee</p>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="box">
                <img src= ${img}>
                <div class = "subtext">     
                <p class = "title">${title}sfeeeeeeee</p>
                <p class = "year">${year}sfeeeeeeeeeeee</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <img src= ${img}>
                <div class = "subtext">     
                <p class = "title">${title}sfeeeeeeee</p>
                <p class = "year">${year}sfeeeeeeeeeeee</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div>
```

Comment: With flex:1 seems to work a bit better. However, it still have the extra block space I believe the container is not resizing to the given extra space is there a way to fix that? Also I want to keep a specific max-width.

Comment: If the container width is not divisible by your max-width, you're going to end up with some "white-space" at certain viewport widths.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "extra block space"

Comment: Yes is it possible to make the container resize to fill in the gap?

Comment: Yes it is, but I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want a certain number of boxes on each row at a fixed width and the container to resize around them?

Comment: I want the boxes to have a max and min width I want both the container and the boxes to resize so that there are no gap when resizing

Comment: I see. You could use javascript to make your container divisible by a fixed box width on resize.

Comment: A ok I understand what I went wrong it just the min width causing the issue I had to put the min-width: 0 and increase the max-width of the boxes a bit to fill in the gap

Answer (score 0):

You can add `justify-content: space-between;`to your `#boxes`
or either use a grid

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
    <div class="box">7</div>
    <div class="box">8</div>
    <div class="box">9</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not want it to be in the center but instead want it like justify-content: start without the extra block space on the right.